# How can I redirect with dynamic parameters using Nginx?

Tags: javascript, nginx, redirect, fetch-api, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm currently receiving a request to my Nginx server at domain1.com/test?param1=123&param2=abc&param3=xyz. I need to take the three parameters, execute a separate HTTP call using those parameters (domain2.com/test?param1=123&param2=abc), which returns an object 'abc123'.

Then based on the response from the call, 302 redirect to domain2.com/endpoint?paramFromCall=abc123&param3=xyz.

Is this possible in Nginx? If not, how should I do this? I'm newer to web dev just trying to get some backend things setup for testing purposes.

I currently have this working by having an index at domain1.com/test that executes this via JS, but it just sets the href. I'd like to 302 instead and not load an index if possible.

Comment: Sounds like a great job for a small PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that can be done inside of nginx, you will need something like a PHP script to handle the logic, like so:

nginx:

```
server {
  # ...

  location /test {
    try_files $uri /redirect.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```

/your/web/root/redirect.php

```php
<?php
$param = file_get_contents('https://domain2.com/test/?param1=' . $_GET['param1'] . '&param2=' . $_GET['param2']);
$redirect = 'https://domain2.com/endpoint/?paramFromCall=' . $param . '&param3=xyz';
header('Location: ' . $redirect, true, 302);
exit;
?>
```